# How to detect internet connection on / off in VueJs NuxtJs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How to detect internet connection on / off in VueJs NuxtJs ?? I want if the internet connection is down it will raise an alert `no internet connection`, if there is internet then it can get data through the API endpoint that has been targeted

Answer (score 1):

Using **$nuxt.isOffline** you can check if there is connection or not.
Check out here in the official nuxtjs [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/$nuxt/).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="$nuxt.isOffline">You are offline</div>
    <nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

**OR**

If you want to check when the browser's connectivity status changes, than you can use **navigator.onLine**. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine).

```
 data() {
     return {
         onLine: navigator.onLine ? true : false,
     }
 }
```